# Erro ImageView cannot be converted to Byte[]

Tags: java, android, sqlite, imagem

Estou montando uma aplicação a qual pretende salvar a imagem no Banco SQLITE. Não estou conseguindo prosseguir pois ocorre o seguinte erro `ImageView cannot be converted to Byte[]`  Peço para serem o mais específicos dado a minha inexperiência. Obrigado

Meu código onde o erro ocorro:

```
   Button btn1Salvar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btSalvar);
    btn1Salvar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Produto pro = new Produto();
            pro.setId(Integer.valueOf(edId.getText().toString()));
            pro.setDescricao(edDescricao.getText().toString());
            pro.setPrecoDeCusto(MonetaryMask.stringMonetarioToDouble(edPrecoDeCusto.getText().toString()));
            pro.setPercDeLucro(Double.valueOf(edPercDeLucro.getText().toString()));
            pro.setPrecoDeVenda(MonetaryMask.stringMonetarioToDouble(edPrecoDeVenda.getText().toString()));
            pro.setImagem(imgView);  // <-- aqui aparece o erro..sublinhado no imgView
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Julgo que o método `pro.setImagem()` espera um `byte[]` para isso tem  primeiro de converter o *Bitmat* que está na ImageView em `byte[]`.

Crie uma função que faça essa conversão:

```
public byte[] convertImageViewToByteArray(ImageView image){
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

Use-a desta forma:

```
pro.setImagem(convertImageViewToByteArray(imgView));
```